# I am having following error running command on Jenkins, when trying to create backend files in S3 bucket

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3, jenkins-pipeline

[31mError refreshing state: AllAccessDisabled: All access to this object has been disabled
status code: 403, request id: 5KMZXB60W6V32CTJ, host id:
I try to  build pipeline on jenkins , creating S3 bucket , but keep getting above error